# Finding rotation axis and angle to align two 3D vector bases

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, rotations

I have asked [this question before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624348/finding-rotation-axis-and-angle-to-align-two-oriented-vectors) and, while the accepted answer solved my problem back then, I am still interested in finding the rotation *axis* and *angle*. Let me rephrase the problem here:

I would like to find the **rotation axis and angle** needed to align two 3D vetor bases, $(\vec a, \vec b, \vec c)$ towards $(\vec d, \vec e, \vec f)$ (meaning that, after the rotation is applied, $(\vec a, \vec b, \vec c)$ equals $(\vec d, \vec e, \vec f)$). These bases are **orthonormal** (i.e. normalized vectors, forming 90-degree angles between any of them). The bases also have the **same handedness** (i.e. no mirroring is necessary to align one towards the other).

Now, due to these bases having the same handedness, there must exist a single rotation that aligns one towards the other (right?).

I would like to know the solution out of curiosity. There's no concern for stability/precision. I've tried solving the original question's accepted answer symbolically, then extracting the axis and angle from the matrix -- did not go so well. Maybe finding the eigenvector would help?

Comment: If you want a linear transformation that maps the first three vectors to the second one, then you don't need to find an axis of rotation and a rotation. Finding an axis of rotation is not generally stable as the transformation approaches the identity matrix where there are 3 eigenvectors with eigenvalue 1. You may want to rethink your approach.

Comment: I might use another approach for my purposes, but still, I am very curious! Even if it means checking for corner cases (just like it's needed for the formula I give at the start of the linked question), I would like to see the general solution to find the axis-angle rotation.

Comment: Given that there are issues of numerical stability in play, I would ask:  what would you *do* with that axis and angle?

Comment: The original idea is to rotate 3D models for placing them at the correct orientation on a Mario Galaxy-esque gravity engine, and to interpolate these orientations between frames (e.g., slow-down effects). I have done it already flawlessly after the linked question, and I can do the interpolation using a strategy other than this. Now I just want to know the solution out of curiosity. Is it possible, even if it means checking for corner cases? And what is the algebraic/algorithmic solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rotation matrix, $R$, can be found relatively easy, such that,

$$
R\,\vec{a} = \vec{d}; \quad R\,\vec{b} = \vec{e}; \quad R\,\vec{c} = \vec{f}.
$$

The rotation matrix/second-order-tensor can be constructed by adding three [dyads](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dyad.html),

$$
R = \vec{d}\vec{a} + \vec{e}\vec{b} + \vec{f}\vec{c}.
$$

When using this notation the multiplication with a vector should be written as a dot product. From this it can also be proven that this expression for $R$ is correct. For example with mapping $\vec{a}$ to $\vec{d}$, the first dyad will return $\vec{d}\vec{a}\cdot\vec{a}$ and since $\vec{a}$ is normalized that is equal to $\vec{d}$. The remaining dot products will yield zero, because the other vectors on the right side of each dyad is orthogonal to $\vec{a}$.

Each dyad can also be written as a 3$\times$3 matrix using the [vector direct product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorDirectProduct.html). The total 3$\times$3 rotation matrix can then be constructed by adding the three 3$\times$3 matrix from the vector direct products.

The axis of rotation is equal to the [eigenvector of the eigenvalue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Determining_the_axis) equal to one. For finding this eigenvector you can take a look at the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155078/closed-form-for-eigenvectors-of-rotation-matrix). In order to find the axis of rotation you have to calculate the following matrix,

$$
R-R^T = 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & \alpha & \beta \\
-\alpha & 0 & \gamma \\
-\beta & -\gamma & 0
\end{bmatrix},
$$

such that the normalized axis of rotation, $\vec{r}$, is equal to,

$$
\vec{r} = \frac{
\begin{bmatrix}
-\gamma & \beta & -\alpha
\end{bmatrix}^T
}{\sqrt{\alpha^2 + \beta^2 + \gamma^2}}.
$$

The [angle of rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Determining_the_angle), $\theta$, can be found according to,

$$
\text{Tr}(R) = 1 + 2\cos\theta,
$$

where $\text{Tr}(R)$ is the [trace](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixTrace.html) of $R$, the sum of its diagonal elements. Due to the cosine you do have to look at the sign of the angle and direction of $\vec{r}$.