# Change from one cartesian co-ordinate system to another by translation and rotation.

Tags: matrices, geometry, transformation, 3d

There are two reasons for me to ask this question:

1. I want to know if my understanding on this issue is correct.
2. To clarify a doubt I have.

I want to change the co-ordinate system of a set of points (Old cartesian coordinates system to New cartesian co-ordinate system). This transformation will involve Translation as well as Rotation. This is what I plan to do:

(Kindly refer to the image attached [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h59115vt6027dpt/Cartesian%20coordinate%20system%20transform.png?dl=0) )

With respect to this image I have a set of points which are in the XYZ coordinate system (Red). I want to change it with respect to the axes UVW (Purple). In order to do so, I have understood that there are two steps involved: Translation and Rotation.

When I translate, I only change the origin. (say, I want the UVW origin at (5,6,7). Then, for all points in my data, the x co-ordinates will be subtracted by 5, y by 6 and z by 7. By doing so. I get a set of Translated data.)

Now I have to apply a rotation transform (on the Translated data). The Rotation matrix is shown in the image. The values Ux, Uy and Uz are the co-ordinates of a point on the U axis which has unit distance from origin. Similarly, the values Vx, Vy and Vz are the coordinates of a point on the V axis which has a unit distance from origin. (I want to know if I am right here.)

Given this information, how can I calculate the value of Wx, Wy and Wx (a point lying on the W axis with unit distance from the origin)? I will know the co-ordinates of the origin {Obviously, (0,0,0), and I have the co-ordinates of points lying at unit distance from origin on the U and V axes. Also, U, V an W are orthonormal.} How can I calculate the 3rd row of rotation matrix R?

Is my approach correct? My ultimate goal is to transform the co-ordinate system. I can calculate points on the U and V axes, but not on the W axis. Keeping this in mind, please provide me with inputs.

(As far as I know, with the Point U (Ux, Uy, Uz), Point V (Vx, Vy and Vz) and the origin, I can define a plane. With this, I can find a point which is at unit distance from (0, 0, 0) in a direction along the plane's normal. How should I do this?)

(Also, if it serves any purpose, I would like to let you know that I am using MATLAB.)

Comment: Your link does not work anymore.

Comment: @Saania, Yes, could you please upload the image directly in here?

Answer (score 6):

This question is somewhat related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1125203/finding-rotation-axis-and-angle-to-align-two-3d-vector-bases), with the main difference that you also have an translation.

Lets first make sure that the notation is clear:

A vector $\vec{v}$ can be represented in the initial Cartesian coordinate system as,

$$
\vec{v} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{e}_x \\ \vec{e}_y \\ \vec{e}_z
\end{bmatrix} \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
v_x \\ v_y \\ v_z
\end{bmatrix}
 = v_x \vec{e}_x + v_y \vec{e}_y + v_z \vec{e}_z,
$$

where $\vec{e}_x$, $\vec{e}_y$ and $\vec{e}_z$ are the orthonormal basis vectors of the initial Cartesian coordinate system.

Similar, the vector $\vec{v}$ can also be represented in the new Cartesian coordinate system as,

$$
\vec{v} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\vec{e}_u \\ \vec{e}_v \\ \vec{e}_w
\end{bmatrix} \cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
v_u \\ v_v \\ v_w
\end{bmatrix} + \vec{o}
 = (v_u + o_u) \vec{e}_u + (v_v + o_v) \vec{e}_v + (v_w + o_w) \vec{e}_w,
$$

where $\vec{o}$ is the vector connecting the initial and new origin and $\vec{e}_u$, $\vec{e}_v$ and $\vec{e}_w$ are the orthonormal basis vectors of the new Cartesian coordinate system, however these can be written as a linear combination of the basis vectors of the initial Cartesian coordinate system,

$$
\vec{e}_u = e_{ux} \vec{e}_x + e_{uy} \vec{e}_y + e_{uz} \vec{e}_z,
$$

$$
\vec{e}_v = e_{vx} \vec{e}_x + e_{vy} \vec{e}_y + e_{vz} \vec{e}_z,
$$

$$
\vec{e}_w = e_{wx} \vec{e}_x + e_{wy} \vec{e}_y + e_{wz} \vec{e}_z.
$$

If $e_{wx}$, $e_{wy}$ and $e_{wz}$ are unknown you can find it by taking the cross product. Assuming that the initial basis vectors are right-handed, then $\vec{e}_w$ can be found with,

$$
\vec{e}_w = \vec{e}_u \times \vec{e}_v = (e_{uy}e_{vz} - e_{uz}e_{vy}) \vec{e}_x + (e_{uz}e_{vx} - e_{ux}e_{vz}) \vec{e}_y + (e_{ux}e_{vy} - e_{uz}e_{vx}) \vec{e}_z,
$$

The rotation of the basis vectors can be calculated with the help of the rotation matrix and can be found with the help of [dyadic products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics),

$$
R = \vec{e}_u\vec{e}_x + \vec{e}_v\vec{e}_y + \vec{e}_w\vec{e}_z,
$$

this yields a second order tensor. In order to calculate the rotation you would have to take the dot product, but if you instead of dyadic products use [vector direct products](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorDirectProduct.html) you can use a normal matrix-vector multiplication. In MATLAB this would can be done with,

```
R = eu * ex' + ev * ey' + ew * ez';
```

such that,

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
v_u \\ v_v \\ v_w
\end{bmatrix}
= R 
\begin{bmatrix}
v_x \\ v_y \\ v_z
\end{bmatrix} + 
\begin{bmatrix}
o_u \\ o_v \\ o_w
\end{bmatrix}.
$$